# Search and maintain values

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show the input field values and selected options after
search. Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="number" id="number" type="text" value="<?=$number?>">
    <select name="Country_Name" id="Country_Name">
        <option value="">Select</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE `is_deleted`=0";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
?>  
        <option  value="<?=$row['country_value']?>" >
           <?=$row['Country_Name']?>
        </option>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="searchbtn">
</form>
```

The selected item will comes from database. The name of the table is country. 
And columns are: country_id, Country_Name, country_value

[image: database columns picture]

I have used this for keep the input field value:

```
 $number = (isset($_POST["number"])) ? $_POST["number"] : "";
```

But this format not working with selected options. How can I do that with php or javascript?

Comment: `<form action="post">` should be changed to `<form method="post" action=" -- a URL here -- ">`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake..

Comment: are you using something in form action? or did you just change the code to what I asked it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to set selected attribute for options.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="number" id="number" type="text" value="<?=$number?>">
<select name="Country_Name" id="Country_Name">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE `is_deleted`=0";
                    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
                    ?>  
                <option  value="<?=$row['country_value']?>" <?=($country_selected ==$row['country_value']? "selected":"" )?> ><?=$row['Country_Name']?></option>
                <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </select>
```

values from post form

```
$number = (isset($_POST["number"])) ? $_POST["number"] : "";
$country_selected = (isset($_POST["Country_Name"])) ? $_POST["Country_Name"] : "";
```